# Boost ASIO - Why basic_stream_socket::available() return zero?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, flatbuffers

I am using Boost Asio and FlatBuffers to send messages over TCP.

Here is how I start the server:

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "Database/MySQLConnection.h"
#include "Implementation/LoginDatabase.h"
#include "Banner.h"
#include "Server/Server.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
using namespace Vibranium;

int main() {
    //Don't mind Logger::FatalError it's just for coloring!
    Banner::Show(Logger::Error,"AuthServer");
    Config config("AuthServer");
    std::string defaultPort = "8080";
    MySQLConnectionInfo mySqlConnectionInfo(config, "LoginDatabaseInfo");
    LoginDatabaseConnection loginDatabaseConnection(mySqlConnectionInfo);
    loginDatabaseConnection.LoadDatabase();

    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        Server s(io_service, std::stoi(config.GetConfigValue("AuthServerPort", defaultPort)));
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Server.h`:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace Vibranium {
    class Server {
    public:
        Server(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, short port)
                : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
                  socket_(io_service) {
            do_accept();
            Logger::Log("Server Started! Listening on Port("+std::to_string(port)+")", Logger::Success, true);
        }
        static std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Client>> Clients;

    private:
        void do_accept();
        int incrementor = 0;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
        tcp::socket socket_;
    };

}
```

`Server.cpp`:

```
#include "Server.h"
#include "Client.h"

using namespace Vibranium;
std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Client>> Server::Clients;
void Server::do_accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
   [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
   {
       if (!ec)
       {
           incrementor++;
           std::string sIncrementor = std::to_string(incrementor);
           Logger::Log("New Connection (ID: " + sIncrementor + ")",Logger::Success);
           std::shared_ptr<Client> c = std::make_shared<Client>(std::move(socket_));
           c->start();
           c->connectionId = incrementor;
           Server::Clients.push_back(c);
       }

       do_accept();
   });
}
```

`Client.h`:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

namespace Vibranium{
    class Client: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
    {
    public:
        Client(tcp::socket socket)
        : socket(std::move(socket))
        {
        }
        void start();
        int connectionId;
        tcp::socket socket;
        void Send(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, const std::string& message);
        void Disconnect() const;
    private:
        void read_message();
        Packet _packet;
    };
}
```

`Client.cpp`:

```
#include "Client.h"
#include "Server.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include "AccountRole_Packet_generated.h"
#include "string"

using namespace Vibranium;

void Vibranium::Client::start() {
    read_message();
}

void Vibranium::Client::Send(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, const std::string& message) {
/*    auto self(shared_from_this());
    _packet.PreparePacket(serverOpcode, message);
    size_t request_length = sizeof(_packet.data_)/sizeof(*_packet.data_);
    boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(_packet.data_, request_length),
     [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t *//*length*//*)
     {
         if (ec)
             Logger::Log("Message sent failed to " + std::to_string(connectionId),Logger::Error);
     });*/
}

void Vibranium::Client::read_message() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    std::cout << "Wholesize:" << socket.available() << std::endl;
    if(socket.available() == 0){
        read_message();
        return;
    }
    _packet.body_.prepare(socket.available());
    boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(&_packet.body_, socket.available()),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if ((boost::asio::error::eof == ec) || (boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec))
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
        else
        {

            const char *HEADER = "ABVG";
            const char* buffIdentifier = flatbuffers::GetBufferIdentifier(&_packet.body_);
            bool hasIdentifier = flatbuffers::BufferHasIdentifier(&_packet.body_,HEADER);

            std::cout << "Builder Identifier" << buffIdentifier << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Builder Has Identifier" << hasIdentifier << std::endl;
            auto ac = GetAccountRole_Packet(&_packet.body_);
            std::cout << "ID" << ac->id() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "NAME:" << ac->name()->c_str() << std::endl;
            //read_body_size();
        }
    });
}


void Vibranium::Client::Disconnect() const {
    Logger::Log("Disconnected ID: " + std::__cxx11::to_string(this->connectionId), Logger::Error, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < Vibranium::Server::Clients.size(); ++i) {
        if(Vibranium::Server::Clients[i]->connectionId == this->connectionId)
            Vibranium::Server::Clients.erase(Vibranium::Server::Clients.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Here is how I send Message:

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
std::string str = "ABCDEFG";
auto name = builder.CreateString(str);
auto accountRole = Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet(builder,5,name);
const char *HEADER = "ABVG";
builder.Finish(accountRole, HEADER);
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buf,size));
```

`Packet.h`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "string"
#include "Protocol/ServerOpcode.h"
#include "boost/asio.hpp"

class Packet {
public:
    Packet()
    {
    }
    boost::asio::streambuf body_;
    void PreparePacket(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, std::string message);
};
```

I've added into `read_message` in order to stop crashing when `socket.available() == 0`.

```
if(socket.available() == 0){
    read_header();
    return;
}
```

What I can't understand is why when I start the server and send several messages the out for the first few is as expected:

```
New Connection (ID: 1213410638)
Wholesize:40
Builder IdentifierABVG
Builder Has Identifier1
ID5
NAME:ABCDEFG
New Connection (ID: 1213410639)
Wholesize:40
Builder IdentifierABVG
Builder Has Identifier1
ID5
NAME:ABCDEFG
New Connection (ID: 1213410640)
Wholesize:40
Builder IdentifierABVG
Builder Has Identifier1
ID5
NAME:ABCDEFG
New Connection (ID: 1213410641)
```

And then suddenly out of nowhere on the next message I see this:

```
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Wholesize:0
Builder IdentifierABVG
Builder Has Identifier1
ID5
```

Why this `Wholesize:0` is happening on such randomness?

I track the messages I send over tcp with:

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -d any port 8085 -q
```

and for every message I send does not matter it shows `Wholesize:0` or not I see the following output:

```
T 127.0.0.1:33174 -> 127.0.0.1:8085 [AP]
....ABVG........................ABCDEFG.
```

So where is my mistake, why `Wholesize:0` keeps on showing here and there on complete random behavior, is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: Where has `ngrep` been the rest of my life? Thank you for including that tool!

Comment: Is there more code? It's really hard to say anything with just the code shown.

Comment: In which code you are interested in? In starting of the server ?

Comment: data doesn't arrive into a socket instantaneously, you'd expect `available` to return `0` until the data has arrived, you need to call `async_read` to wait for data

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am already calling `async_read` as you can see in the question.

Comment: Yes I can see that but you are calling `available` first

Comment: But you're calling `available` *before* calling `async_read`.  How and when is `Vibranium::Client::read_message` being called?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am caling `available` first so I can get the size of the buffer otherwise how can I get to to provide it in `boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&_packet.body_, socket.available()),[this, self](boost::system::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)`

Comment: Also I need the size so I can `_packet.body_.prepare(socket.available());` otherwise how can I resize the `boost::asio::streambuf` ?

Comment: @sehe I've updated my question adding more code.

Comment: Thats a problem for your protocol, either you just read as much as you can and figure out what it means afterwards or you have to prefix your message with a length. [async_read_until](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) may be useful. you should never rely on `available` for much it's likely to be 0 or otherwise less than what you expect it to be

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't have delimiter so `async_read_until` will most likely not work. How can I add delimiter ?

Comment: If you're not experienced in network protocol design I'd recommend using an off the shelf protocol like HTTP which then has the additional benefit of being able to use off the shelf libraries

Comment: I am here to use boost asio with TCP and binary protocol.

Comment: @AlanBirtles what I can do is I can prefix the size of the message.